# How can I control the order of G+ circles in the new Google Plus design?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-circles

I used to be able to sort the order of my G+ circles in the classic view.

A couple of months ago, Google completely removed the classic view, and I miss the ability to sort.

How can I change the order of the G+ circles in the new Google Plus design?

Answer (score -1):

As someone who scraped the bottom of the barrel to figure out that exact same thing, I am left to conclude that there is no way to do so.  Either they overlooked adapting it to the new view or that is one of several passive ways that they're trying to eventually kill off this platform.